# Is it a good practice to directly write SQL query in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am making an application with very huge data and multiple joins. Is it a bad practice to right away use the full sql string in rails? What are the downsides of writing the full sql query in rails?

Comment: A lot of complex queries are much easier and cleaner to express in SQL, they're also much easier to tune in SQL. I do it all the time, I also use real FKs, CHECK constrains, triggers, and other heretical things with wild abandon.

Comment: And I sometimes walk to the store because there are other benefits over taking the car, even though sometimes I am forced to drive because I'm not going to get there fast enough otherwise.  Just like it is going to take me longer to write web apps if I do them in raw SQL.  The OP asked whether it would be a good idea to use raw SQL while using a framework designed to insulate him from doing so (for better or worse).  The fact remains he hasn't given a reason why in his particular case he would need to do so.  And I maintain that without a specific reason it's not the best practice.

Comment: What if we are talking about 1.7 million coloumns which will keep increasing and database in EAV model !!

Comment: 1.7 million columns?  In one table?

Comment: Sorry my mistake .... 1.7 million rows !!

Comment: 1.7 million rows is not that significant.  At least not enough that it would likely be a factor in your decision whether or not to use raw SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's only bad practice if you do it without understanding the alternatives.

That said there is rarely a reason to do this.  The framework encapsulates it for you and the benefit is that you have to write less code.  The other benefit is database independence.  The more direct queries you write, the more likely you'll write something that will break when you switch database engines.

It is easy to test.  If you are using the framework properly (i.e. optimizing ActiveRecord as you will find discussed in numerous articles) and still feel like your queries are too slow...you can always benchmark direct queries.

But not knowing how to do something using ActiveRecord associations is not a good reason to resort to direct SQL.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Database independence is largely a myth, no ORM will insulate you from the differences between databases. That's why there are so many "it worked in development with SQLite but broken on Heroku with PostgreSQL" questions around and why we always tell people to develop and deploy on identical stacks.

Comment: Put a group of developers in a room and have them write a web app with nothing but PHP with no framework and direct SQL queries.  Then put another similar group in a room and have them write a web app with Rails or any other good ORM-based framework with no direct SQL.  Are you going to tell me that both groups will have the same amount of database portability issues?

Comment: Yes, I will say that. The show stopper portability problems (GROUP BY behavior, collation issues, casting, NULL handling edge cases, case sensitivity of LIKE, ...) will be identical, the trivial ones (things like different identifier quoting) are easy to fix and not worth worrying about. I know this because I've dealt with these issues for years and I've seen enough people that blindly trusted their ORM and had to rewrite significant chunks of their database when things broken in interesting ways when deployed.

Answer (score 2):

SQL is not a 'bad practice' *per se*. Database systems have plenty of native SQL ways of doing things that would be much slower to execute and more complex to write and maintain if written in Ruby. Like Oracle's Analytic Functions.

That said, ActiveRecord is pretty easy to write **and** *you probably aren't going to get a performance boost just by using a SQL query*. At least not if the query you write resembles the query ActiveRecord would have written anyway! ;)

Perhaps you should try to work with ActiveRecord and only resort to SQL if you hit problems you can't solve another way. That way you keep your code simple until you need to do it another way (i.e. don't 'optimise early').

I generally try to make things work in ActiveRecord (or DataMapper or Sequel or whatever), but I have definitely resorted finder_sql when the job needed doing quickly and I couldn't get where I wanted to go using the ORM's 'sugar'. Other times I have based a rails object on a single massive view in the database.

Hope this helps.

:D

Answer (score 1):

If you need more powerfull syntax than provides standard ActiveRecord module, see [meta_where](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where) gem.